Is it reliable to just use bind method's return error to determine bind to a node success or not?
I have some questions about calling k8s client-go's bind method, when we need to bind a pod to a node.
Currently, we use the return error of bind method to determine bind  successfully or not,
I wonder if there exists the situation that bind method returns some time out error, while
in the k8s side, the pod binds to the node successfully, if so, should we handle this situation?
use the return error of bind method to determine bind  successfully or not, should be  reliable
